# Cant get all attribute values

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am havning trouble to get the value of some attributes in an "embed" webelement. I have following WebElement in a page, showing a PDF in the browser:

```
<embed id="plugin" type="application/x-google-chrome-pdf" src="https://A-link.dk/plan/53--4c-c3-d5cd72ba/printGenerate.do?target=ON_RESIDENT&amp;format=PDF&amp;saveAsDocument=false&amp;printSelectionId=&amp;_=49365165116" stream-url="blob:chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/95052284-bc11-44c9-a261-6000f48a75d4" 
headers="Cache-Control: 
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="planDto.pdf";
Content-Type: application/pdf
Date: Mon, 23 Jan 2017 14:47:47 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=90
Pragma: public
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
" background-color="0xFF525659" top-toolbar-height="56" full-frame="">
```

I am trying to get the headers attribute string using selenium chrome webdriver.
Using the Chrome developer console i can retrieve the value with

```
document.getElementsByTagName("embed")[0].getAttribute("headers")
```

but in selenium java when i try this:

```
String header = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver.getDriver())
    .executeScript("return document.getElementsByTagName(\"embed\")[0].getAttribute(\"headers\");");
```

I get an empty string.
Beside that i tried also:

```
WebElement img = driver.findElement(By.tagName("embed"));
String header = img.getAttribute("headers");
```

But this returns NULL.

It works fine when i try to get the src attribute using

```
String src = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver.getDriver())
    .executeScript("return document.getElementsByTagName(\"embed\")[0].getAttribute(\"src\");");
```

As a bonus I can tell that I am only interested in the filename, so if there is a better/more easy solution to get that please enlighten me.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE V1**
Using google developer tools I can copy this source code

```
  <html dir="ltr" lang="da"><head>
  <base href="chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="import" href="elements/viewer-error-screen/viewer-error-screen.html">
  <link rel="import" href="elements/viewer-page-indicator/viewer-page-indicator.html">
  <link rel="import" href="elements/viewer-page-selector/viewer-page-selector.html">
  <link rel="import" href="elements/viewer-password-screen/viewer-password-screen.html">
  <link rel="import" href="elements/viewer-pdf-toolbar/viewer-pdf-toolbar.html">
  <link rel="import" href="elements/viewer-zoom-toolbar/viewer-zoom-toolbar.html">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome://resources/css/text_defaults.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome://resources/css/roboto.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<title>Print</title></head>
<body>

<viewer-pdf-toolbar id="toolbar" style="transform-origin: 50% 0px 0px; transform: none;"></viewer-pdf-toolbar>

<div id="sizer" style="width: 773px; height: 2239px;"></div>
<viewer-password-screen id="password-screen"></viewer-password-screen>

<viewer-zoom-toolbar id="zoom-toolbar" style="right: -8.5px; bottom: 0px;"></viewer-zoom-toolbar>

<viewer-page-indicator id="page-indicator" style="top: 0px; opacity: 0;"></viewer-page-indicator>

<viewer-error-screen id="error-screen"></viewer-error-screen>


<script src="toolbar_manager.js"></script><iron-a11y-announcer></iron-a11y-announcer>
<script src="viewport.js"></script>
<script src="open_pdf_params_parser.js"></script>
<script src="navigator.js"></script>
<script src="viewport_scroller.js"></script>
<script src="zoom_manager.js"></script>
<script src="pdf_scripting_api.js"></script>
<script src="chrome://resources/js/util.js"></script>
<script src="browser_api.js"></script>
<script src="pdf.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>

<embed id="plugin" type="application/x-google-chrome-pdf" src="https://A-link.dk/questionnaire/schemeanswers/669bb12b-b7c2-4223-96d2-1ccca26147ce/printSchemeAnswer.do?reportId=" stream-url="blob:chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/7aeb6fee-140b-4368-8b4b-537a019387de" headers="Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=&quot;questionnaire.pdf&quot;
Content-Length: 23414
Content-Type: application/pdf
Date: Tue, 24 Jan 2017 13:16:49 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
" background-color="0xFF525659" top-toolbar-height="56" full-frame=""></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is getting you right element? `WebElement img = driver.findElement(By.tagName("embed"));`

Try with `WebElement img = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("embed#plugin"));` and see if it returns null.

Comment: It is not a problem to find the embed element, but the problem is the attribute 'headers' that return an empty string using selenium chrome webdriver 2.27

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this could be the feasible solution for your problem. But as you are interested only to get `filename` under `<embed>` following code might help you to do the same -

```
String expectedData = null;

// Get the whole embed tag 
String tagdata = driver.findElement(By.id("plugin")).getAttribute("outerHTML");

// use regex expression to extract only your required file from the headers attribute
 Pattern patern = Pattern.compile("filename=\"(.+)\";");
 Matcher match = patern.matcher(tagdata);
 if (match.find()) 
 {
    expectedData = match.group(1);
 }
 System.out.println("Result is ="+ expectedData);
```

**Explanation:-** The above code will get the `<embed>` tag data and match the `regex` of `filename` in that and retrieve the result as your expected file

Comment: I can get the outerHTML but it is still missing the attrubutes: headers, stream-url. And the type attribute, has different value in selenium type=(application/pdf) vs chrome dev tool type=(application/x-google-chrome-pdf)

Comment: what do you mean by missing attribute ? the code is for extract the file name using regex expression. If you want to extract some other things then you have to use other regex expression for that

Comment: the string output of outerHTML: <embed 
width="100%" 
height="100%" 
name="plugin" 
id="plugin" 
src="https://a-link.dk/plan/5df79f63-2040-424c-a5c3-d54b9bcd72ba/printGenerate.do?target=ON_RESIDENT&amp;format=PDF&amp;saveAsDocument=false&amp;printSelectionId=&amp;_=14834" 
type="application/pdf" 
internalinstanceid="32">

Comment: more then one `<embed>`tags are there in your html ?

Comment: There is only on tag using chrome console: document.getElementsByTagName("embed") I get only one (embed#plugin)

Comment: Its little bit tricky to found what actually happening. just analyze the fact by manually check the element in chrome weather it present will all attributes or have missing attribute or the element with same `id`. I'm not clear with `document.getElementsByTagName("embed")` if you are checking this using `webdriver` then there are chances to present more then one `<embed>` because it returns only first `embed` tag. Is it possible to share your site url ?

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName returns a list. if I e.g. execute document.getElementsByTagName("script") I get 11 element using the chrome developer tools. 2 secs I will upload the html source code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133896/discussion-between-narendra-rajput-and-jens-henrik).